# Factor a Vector

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

Does there exist a function in Mathematica that simply takes out a common factor from a vector/list of expressions? This seems like such a simple operation that I am surprised that I could not find it in Google or the Mathematica help. It could return the common factor and the list without it:

```
Function[{a b c , b c, c d}] = {c,{a b, b, d}}
```

Or it could even simply return the common factor:

```
Function[{a b c , b c, c d}] = c
```

edit: sorry I was not completely clear. It would factor out algebraic expression too. So:

```
Function[{x^2 y, x}]
```

would yield:

```
{x,{x y, 1}}
```

Comment: *A* "common factor", where all having it is a given? `Intersection @@ list`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
test = {x^2 y, x};

p = PolynomialGCD @@ test
{p, test/p}

test = {a b c e, b c e, c d e, e c};

p = PolynomialGCD @@ test
{p, test/p}

(*

{x, {x y, 1}}
{c e, {a b, b, d, 1}}

*)
```

Comment: Thank you! PolynomialGCD was that function!