# Extract common factor from vector or matrix

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector, factorization

I can't believe this hasn't been asked before but I can't find anything.

Is there a way to convince `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` to extract common factors from matrices as it does from sums?

- **Exhibit A:**

  ```
  {a/(2 c), b/(2 c), d/(2 c), e/(2 c)} // FullSimplify // FullSimplify
  ```

  gives

  ```
  {a/(2 c), b/(2 c), d/(2 c), e/(2 c)}
  ```

  In reality, I have a 2x2 matrix, but the result is effectively the same. A solution to my problem should ideally not depend on the dimensions/layout of the (potentially nested) list.
- **Exhibit B:**

  ```
  a/(2 c) + b/(2 c) + d/(2 c) + e/(2 c) // FullSimplify
  ```

  gives

  ```
  (a + b + d + e)/(2 c)
  ```

I did see [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44500/factor-a-vector), but I'm just asking about rearranging, I don't actually need access to the polynomial GDC in a separate variable or anything, so I was wondering if this was possible with `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` somehow.

Comment: `{a,b,c} x` is not a "stable form", it would immediately evaluate to `{a x, b x, c x}`.  The question is interesting, I'm just mentioning that it's not possible to keep the expression in this form.  You'd have to store `{a,b,c}` and `x` separately.

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you link me to some background reading about "stable forms"?

Comment: I just made that term up, you won't find much by searching for it.  All I meant to say is that it evaluates further immediately.  A similar example would be `x+x`, which evaluates immediately to `2x`, or `Sin[Pi]` which evaluates to `0`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I see. I'd still be interested, what's going on under the hood. But I guess that means my only option is indeed to flatten the input and feed it to `PolynomialGDC`. Feel free to close as duplicate.

Comment: You *can* actually keep it in that form using `Hold[{a, b} x]` or `HoldForm[{a,b} x]`, but held expressions aren't very suitable for algebraic manipulation.  `HoldForm` is useful though for just *displaying* the expression in certain form that is easier for us humans to parse.

Comment: I don't know much about the internals of `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`, but I vaguely recall that they make their decisions about what forms are "simplest" based on some sort of cost function, and that there have been previous questions asking about how to manipulate the cost function used by `Simplify` in order to tailor the output to a particular form that was considered 'optimal' by the question-asker. Is there any way that cost-function modification could be applied here, or is that not possible?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus You can manipulate both the `ComplexityFunction` (which wouldn't be necessary) *and* the `TransformationFunctions` (which would), but because the result the OP was looking for auto-evaluates, it wouldn't be of any help.  Theoretically you could include a transformation function that applies `Hold` after extracting the common factor, but since `Simplify` won't be able to further transform held expressions, and since the factor extraction would need to be done manually anyway, it makes little sense to integrate this into `Simplify`.

Comment: Perhaps leaving an inactive expression might be useful? `facMat[m_] := m /. mat : IgnoringInactive[{{f_ _ ..} ..}?MatrixQ] :> Inactivate[f (mat /. IgnoringInactive[f i_] :> i), Times]`

Comment: A good application of such a solution would be to vectorize expressions so that they could be computed much more quickly.

Answer (score 7):

A toy approach is as follows:

```
 FactorizeCommonFactor[tensor_?TensorQ] := 
  Block[{GCDListv, cfactor, tenfact, tenfactmf, facten},
   cfactor := PolynomialGCD @@ Flatten@tensor;
   tenfact := (1/cfactor)*tensor;
   tenfactmf := MatrixForm[tenfact];
   Piecewise[{{Return[{"Common Factor" -> cfactor, tenfact, 
        Inactivate[cfactor*tenfactmf]}], 
      cfactor =!= 1}, {Print[
       "The tensor cannot be expressed as a multiple of another
tensor"], cfactor === 1}}];
   ];
```

Test:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am not seriously proposing this as a solution but it was fun to play with.

```
Block[{Plus},
  Simplify[
    Plus @@ {a/(2 c), b/(2 c), d/(2 c), e/(2 c)}
  ] /. Plus -> Defer@*List
]
```

> ```
> {a, b, d, e}/Sqrt[2]
> ```

---

I do not recommend this in practice as `Plus` is a very low level operator and it is not clear what `Block` actually accomplishes.

1. As noted elsewhere<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89832/121)</sup> heads like `Plus` and `Equal` have rules that fire on numbers and packed arrays even while Blocked.  One cannot be sure that `Simplify` does not also have specific handling of `Plus` that `Block` does not affect therefore this seem unreliable.
2. `Plus` is such a basic function that it is probably used in a lot of internal code that we *do not* wish to affect, and `Block` is an indiscriminate tool.

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I am increasingly forgetful, and recently I've been busy, so I do this a lot I'm afraid. :-/

Comment: This post is from many years ago, is there something more about the extraction of common factors in vectors or matrices?

Answer (score 4):

`arrayFactorList[array]` factors an array à la `FactorList`, which can then be put in the form `Inactive[Times][scalarCommonFactor, array]` (see examples):

```
arrayFactorList[array_?ArrayQ] :=
 FactorList@Total[
    MapIndexed[# \[FormalCapitalA][#2] &, array, {ArrayDepth[array]}],
     ArrayDepth[array]] /. \[FormalCapitalA][i_] :> 
   SparseArray[{i -> 1}, Dimensions[array]]
```

Example 1:

```
arrayFactorList[{a/(2 c), b/(2 c), d/(2 c), e/(2 c)}]
GroupBy[Power @@@ %, Head[#] === SparseArray &] //
   Map@Apply@Times //
  Apply@Inactive@Times //
 Normal
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Example 2:

```
arrayFactorList[{{1/Sqrt[2]}, {0}, {0}, {1/Sqrt[2]}}]
GroupBy[Power @@@ %, Head[#] === SparseArray &] //
   Map@Apply@Times //
  Apply@Inactive@Times //
 Normal
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]