# How to get a factor extracted from a list?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify the following expression:

```
{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}
```

How can I get the factor `1/Sqrt[2]` in front of the parenthesis like:

```
1/Sqrt[2] {1, 1}
```

??

Comment: It is not possible to put the expression into that form, as the multiplication would evaluate immediately.  It may be possible to have `1/Sqrt[2]` and  `{1, 1}` as separate results, but in that case it is very important to make it clear what factors should or shouldn't be extracted.  What about `{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3], 7, 5/2}`?

Comment: I get your argument. However, to rapidly grasp the symmetry of a matrix by eye (I'm talking of 3x3 or 4x4 matrix) one would reduce/simplify the matrix. I just wanted to enforce MMA to do that for me... Your example is of course totally asymmetric :D

Comment: Maybe just multiply manually with the factor that seems relevant by visual inspection (`Sqrt[2]` here).  Or even use `MatrixPlot`, which should help in quickly determining a symmetry visually (then verify manually).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70131/extract-common-factor-from-vector-or-matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
v = {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]};

c = PolynomialGCD @@ v;

c*Defer @@ {v/c}
```

> ```
> {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view it you can try this.

Here is a mixed matrix with some parts that have `Sqrt[2]` in the denominator and some parts that do not.

```
matrix = {{1/Sqrt[2], 2/Sqrt[2]}, {3, Sqrt[2]}, {4, 3/Sqrt[2]},
          {2./Sqrt[2], a/Sqrt[2]}};

MatrixForm[matrix]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \sqrt{2} \\
 3 & \sqrt{2} \\
 4 & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 1.41421 & \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now multiply it by the `Sqrt[2]`

```
matrix2=Sqrt[2]*matrix;

MatrixForm[matrix2]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 \sqrt{2} & 2 \\
 4 \sqrt{2} & 3 \\
 2. & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

`matrix2` the simplified matrix with `1/Sqrt[2]` factored out.

In order to see it with the `1/Sqrt[2]` outside try

```
HoldForm[1/Sqrt[2]] HoldForm[Evaluate[matrix2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can get a temporary peek at the matrix with `1/Sqrt[2]` moved to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Given the vector

```
v = {1/Sqrt[2], 4/Sqrt[2], (x + 3)/Sqrt[2]};
```

The following code

```
c = PolynomialGCD @@ v;
Print[c, " ", (v/c) // MatrixForm];
```

Outputs what you want

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
4\\
3 + x\\
\end{pmatrix}$$