# Factor out common terms from a list of terms

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

I was looking for an automated way to factor out common terms from a list.

Example (assuming `n<1`):

```
 list={(1 + r^2)^(-1/2 + n/2) (1 + w^2)^(-1/2 - n/2) (1 + r^(1 - n) w^(1 + n)) x12^-n, 
       r^(1 - n) (1 + r^2)^(-1/2 + n/2) w^(1 + n) (1 + w^2)^(-1/2 - n/2) x12^-n, 
       (1 + r^2)^(-1/2 + n/2) (1 + w^2)^(-1/2 - n/2) x12^-n}
```

Expected output:

```
(1 + r^2)^(-1/2 + n/2) (1 + w^2)^(-1/2 - n/2)   x12^-n  {  (1 + 
r^(1 - n) w^(1 + n)) , r^(1 - n)  w^(1 + n), 1  } 
or 
{ CommonFactor->(1 + r^2)^(-1/2 + n/2) (1 + w^2)^(-1/2 - n/2)   x12^-n , 
  { (1 + r^(1 - n) w^(1 + n)) , r^(1 - n)  w^(1 + n), 1  }}
```

There are some ways ([Extract common factor from vector or matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70131/extract-common-factor-from-vector-or-matrix)) to factor out common terms using `PolynomialGCD`, which works in most of the cases, however, in this case, it does not do it properly (probably due to the unknown `n`?)
Using their approach I get

```
 {"CommonFactor" ->   r^(-2 n) (1 + r^2)^(-(1/2) + n/2) (1 + w^2)^(-1 - n) x12^(-2n), 
  {r^(2 n) (1 + r^2)^(1/2 + 1/2 (-1 + n) - n/2) (1 + w^2)^(1/2 + n/2) (1 + r^(1 - n) w^(1 + n)) x12^n, 
   r^(1 + n) w^(1 + n) (1 + w^2)^(1/2 + n/2) x12^n, 
   r^(2 n) (1 + w^2)^(1/2 + n/2) x12^n}}
```

which is not the wanted behavior. `Assuming[0<n<1` also does not help.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{#, list/#} &@Fold[Intersection, list]
```

$$\left\{\left(r^2+1\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} \left(w^2+1\right)^{-\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} \text{x12}^{-n},\left\{r^{1-n} w^{n+1}+1,r^{1-n} w^{n+1},1\right\}\right\}$$

---

**EDIT** *a possible failsafe strategy where the* `Intersection` *will likely not work*

Let's say the original `list` is now called `alist`:

```
alist = {(1 + r^2)^(-1/2 + n/2) (1 + w^2)^(-1/2 - n/2) (1 + 
     r^(1 - n) w^(1 + n)) x12^-n, 
  r^(1 - n) (1 + r^2)^(-1/2 + n/2) w^(1 + n) (1 + w^2)^(-1/2 - 
      n/2) x12^-n, (1 + r^2)^(-1/2 + n/2) (1 + w^2)^(-1/2 - 
      n/2) x12^-n}
```

and another list is called `blist`:

```
blist = {a^-n (1 + a^n b), b, a^-n}
```

Then

```
{Head /@ alist, Head /@ blist}
```

> ```
> {{Times, Times, Times}, {Times, Symbol, Power}}
> ```

A possible strategy could be to check the `Head` in advance and choose `1` or another method instead of the `Intersection`. As an example:

```
If[! SameQ @@ (Head /@ #), 1, Fold[Intersection, #]] & /@ {alist, 
  blist}
```

> {(1 + r^2)^(-(1/2) + n/2) (1 + w^2)^(-(1/2) - n/2) x12^-n, 1}

Comment: Great answer. Even shorter `Intersection @@ list` ;)

Comment: Works in the OP's case but not in general, neither with `list = Expand[list]` nor `list = {r x + r^(2 - n) y, r (x + 2 y)}`.

Comment: I think this would be too much to ask to Mathematica. I was expecting to use `Assuming n>1` etc. Probably one has to make the expressions in a particular form (according to the requirement) and then apply `Intersection`. I find both a combination of `Intersection` & `PolynomialGCD` useful for some of my other cases similar to the one in the question.

Comment: @Boogeyman I looked at `TreeForm` and realized that parts of the tree were identical. Once you expand this expression, the peculiarities of internal `FullForm` representations would prohibit such a filtering in general as a structural intersection is being calculated, not a computational one.

Comment: @Syed, Is it possible to apply a failsafe to your method? For example `{a^-n (1+a^n b),b,a^-n}` is one such example where `Intersection` fails, but `PolynomialGCD` works as expected. But in the `Intersection` way, although it can not find the common factor, it tries anyway to write the intersection. One would expect to return in such cases just a common factor `1` instead of errors and symbolical form of the common factor with intersection of terms.

Comment: Please see update for a possible failsafe mechanism. Do try this with the `PolynomialGCD` and see if it helps.

Comment: Also useful to put `|| (AllTrue[list,Head[#] === Symbol &])` in the condition if `list={a,b,c}` which is also a problem for `Intersection`.